# Comparing 2 arrays and their objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to compare these 2 objects based on `topicID` and `items->item->id` and return true for being same? (it must ignore `unique` element)

```
const var1 = [
  {
    unique: "8123456",
    topicID: "1234",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "x",
        },
        {
          id: "y",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    unique: "123456",
    topicID: "123",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "b",
        },
        {
          id: "a",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

const var2 = [
  {
    unique: "3123456",
    topicID: "123",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "a",
        },
        {
          id: "b",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    unique: "2123456",
    topicID: "1234",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "y",
        },
        {
          id: "x",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Are you trying to find duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

```js
a = [{ value:"4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display:"Jamsheer"}, { value:"644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display:"Muhammed"}, { value:"b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display:"Ravi"}, { value:"e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display:"Ajmal"},  { value:"a63a6f77-c637-454e-abf2-dfb9b543af6c", display:"Ryan"}]
b = [{ value:"4a55eff3-1e0d-4a81-9105-3ddd7521d642", display:"Jamsheer", $$hashKey:"008"}, { value:"644838b3-604d-4899-8b78-09e4799f586f", display:"Muhammed", $$hashKey:"009"}, { value:"b6ee537a-375c-45bd-b9d4-4dd84a75041d", display:"Ravi", $$hashKey:"00A"}, { value:"e97339e1-939d-47ab-974c-1b68c9cfb536", display:"Ajmal", $$hashKey:"00B"}]

function comparer(otherArray){
  return function(current){
    return otherArray.filter(function(other){
      return other.value == current.value && other.display == current.display
    }).length == 0;
  }
}

var onlyInA = a.filter(comparer(b));
var onlyInB = b.filter(comparer(a));

result = onlyInA.concat(onlyInB);

console.log(result);
```

**Here is put your required data and use this code you will get success**

Comment: It doesn't work with the objects I shared :(

Comment: objectsEqual(o1[p], o2[p]) 
this line is for object in you case

objectsEqual(o1[p.items.item.id], o2[p.items.item.id)

Comment: still couldn't make it work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

**Try using:**

```js
const var1 = [
  {
    unique: "8123456",
    topicID: "1234",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "x",
        },
        {
          id: "y",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    unique: "123456",
    topicID: "123",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "b",
        },
        {
          id: "a",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

const var2 = [
  {
    unique: "3123456",
    topicID: "123",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "a",
        },
        {
          id: "b",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    unique: "2123456",
    topicID: "1234",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "y",
        },
        {
          id: "x",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];

const var3 = [
  {
    unique: "8123456",
    topicID: "1234",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "x",
        },
        {
          id: "y",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  {
    unique: "123456",
    topicID: "123",
    items: {
      item: [
        {
          id: "b",
        },
        {
          id: "a",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
];


function objCompare(object1, object2) {
  const keys1 = Object.keys(object1);
  const keys2 = Object.keys(object2);

  if (keys1.length !== keys2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const key of keys1) {
    const val1 = object1[key];
    const val2 = object2[key];
    const isObj= checkObj(val1) && checkObj(val2);
    if (
      isObj && !objCompare(val1, val2) ||
      !isObj && val1 !== val2
    ) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function checkObj(object) {
  return object != null && typeof object === 'object';
}

console.log(objCompare(var1,var2));
console.log(objCompare(var1,var3));
```

**Hope this helps !!!**

Comment: thanks for your help but in this function it compares all elements, it should only compare `topicID` and `items->item[]->id`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact use case, I'll outline a general idea of how you could go about it.

For each item in the array, generate a key based on the `topicID` and the concatenation of the `id` within `items`. From there, you construct a set of both lots of keys, then compare them. This would work assuming that:

1. There are no duplicates in a single array.
2. You only need to test for "equality". If you need to pull out the duplicated items it's more difficult, but the same approach can be followed.

```js
const constructKey = o =>
    `${o.topicID}_${o.items.item.map(item => item.id).join('')}`

const setEq = (a, b) => a.size === b.size && [...a].every(v => b.has(v));

const var1Keys = new Set(var1.map(constructKey));
const var2Keys = new Set(var2.map(constructKey));

console.log(setEq(var1Keys, var2Keys))
```

EDIT: Based on your comment, it seems as though you want to compare items regardless of order. Something like this:

```
const constructMap = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce(
    (map, { topicID, items }) =>
      map.set(topicID, new Set(items.item.map(({ id }) => id))),
    new Map(),
  )

const setEq = (a, b) => a.size === b.size && [...a].every((v) => b.has(v))

const mapEq = (a, b) =>
  a.size === b.size &&
  [...a.entries()].every(([k, v]) => b.has(k) && setEq(v, b.get(k)))

const var1Map = constructMap(var1)
const var2Map = constructMap(var2)

console.log(mapEq(var1Map, var2Map))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesnt seem to be working :( https://jsfiddle.net/mdap3f72/

Comment: Because you didn't really specify what the problems was. It seems as though you want it to be able to match all items regardless of order. You should clarify in your question what you're looking for.

Comment: I updated the post, if that doesn't do what you want you'll need to take it from there.